# findall specification pageable is taking time for 10 data java spring boot jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Hi I have a table HrCrEmp where i have 132 columns and have several relationship with other tables. I am using a pagination

```
if(sortField == null || sortField.equals("") || sortField.equals("id") ) sortField = "id";
Sort sort = sortDir.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).descending() : Sort.by(sortField).ascending();

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum - 1, pageSize, sort);


Page<HrCrEmp> hrCrEmp = this.hrCrEmpRepository.findAll((Specification<HrCrEmp>) (root, cq, cb) -> {
    //rest of the code;
}
```

But unfortunately this pagination is taking about 40 to 50 seconds to return 10 values; Can anyone please help what might be the issue and how can i sort out this issue in java spring boot.

I have searched for solutions in the net but haven't found any . This is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Measure, figure out what is happening. You say 10 records, but are they really 10 records? Or 10 entityes with a lot of relationships to different tables which are fetched as well. Also page size of 10, on how many records in the database? Which database? What are the specifications you are applying... In short there is too little information to answer this question.

Comment: Please share your entity class

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the `findList` method. `findAll` is a full table query, and I don't know which class your `hrCrEmpRepository` is extends from

Comment: this is extended from ```extends GenericRepository<HrCrEmp>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<HrCrEmp>```

Comment: Maybe you should look at the sql execution plan